# Converting in Smalltalk VisualWorks 7.9.1

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I need to convert a `ByteString` to a `Float32` (Exactly a 32-bit big-endian IEEE 754 floating point number). The `ByteString` is a part of an open sound control stream, received via UDP client.
I've spent a lot of time researching, so I'd like of someone handy with Smalltalk could give me a solution.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be receiving binary data, and not a decimal number in formatted ASCII, I would not recommend to call it ByteString, but rather ByteArray, Strings are an abstraction for containing characters, not bits.

In the case of VisualWorks, there is a class called `UninterpretedBytes` specialized in storing raw data (bits or rather bytes) for later interpretation.
This class has all the message you need to interpret the bytes, like for example `#floatAt:bigEndian`:

```
| yourBinaryStream buffer |
yourBinaryStream := ... insert some code to create your stream here...
buffer:= UninterpretedBytes from: (yourBinaryStream next: 4).
nextFloat := buffer floatAt: 1 bigEndian: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pharo Smalltalk you can do:

```
   (Float readFrom: '4.2') asIEEE32BitWord
```

readFrom: just reads a float from a string, and then you convert it to IEEE 754...

Comment: I'm using visualworks for a school project, i don't have the same packages as pharo, and importing those packages or filing then in from pharo won't work. Float class does not have a "readFrom" method in visualworks.

Answer (score 0):

In VisualWorks you need to use the superclass method `readFrom`: as implemented in class `Number`.
First create a readstream on the string, for example:

```
Number readFrom: '192843.887' readStream
```

Comment: Thx for your help, your solution is indeed working.
But since the float is a part of an OSC-message i managed to do it this way:
`parseFloat


 | oldValue byte1 byte2 byte3 byte4 newValue |

 oldValue := byteStream next: 4. 
 newValue := Float basicNew: 4.
 byte1 := oldValue basicAt: 1.
 byte2 := oldValue basicAt: 2.
 byte3 := oldValue basicAt: 3.
 byte4 := oldValue basicAt: 4.

 newValue basicAt: 1 put: byte1.
 newValue basicAt: 2 put: byte2.
 newValue basicAt: 3 put: byte3.
 newValue basicAt: 4 put: byte4.
 ^newValue` 


Hope this code help someone else.